# Don't declare main/launcher activity in manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

In my app I start an initial setup activity on first startup.

```
// main activity onCreate
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if (PreferencesUtility.firstStartup(this) ) {// helper class to access SharedPreferences
    Intent setupActivity = new Intent(this, SetupActivity.class);
    startActivity(setupActivity);

    finish();
    return;
}
...
...
```

}

This code is working but I think a better place for it would be in my Application class. This wouldn't require to start and finish the main activity immediately after the "initial startup" check...

Is there a way to dynamically choose the startup activity?
I tried to remove the "main" and "launcher" intent filter from Manifest.xml
and added the following code in my Applications onCreate

```
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, LogBookActivity.class);

    startIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);  


    startActivity(startIntent);
```

but nothing was starting up.
I thought that at least my Application's onCreate would be called...

Comment: If you don't specify the Main Activity in the manifest how will the system know which Activity to start?

Comment: I agree with shyam, I do not think, thats possible

Comment: I thought I can place this code in my custom Application class in the onCreate mehtod as posted above

Comment: Where is android doing this? Someone has to read the manifest.xml and launch the configured activity... Shouldn't this be the Application class?

Comment: No. Even if you declare an activity as **MAIN** in Application class, it's already *too late*. Because manifest.xml is being read first before any of your classes. And when the reading is done, the next thing happened is "Which class should I launch first? I launch **MAIN** class first, but I saw none marked as **MAIN**."

Comment: Shouldn't application be created even if I don't declare an activity as launcher? I have a custom Application class which derives from android.app.Application. To be more specific: My plan was to decide in Application.onCreate which activity to launch

Comment: When I place a breakpoint inside Application.onCreate and Activity.onCreate the breakpoint in Application is hit first as long as I keep the Lauhcner/Main intent-filter in my Manifest.xml. When I remove this nothing is called...

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have to launch a separate activity for this?
Why don't you create a fragment for those initial steps then you don't have to terminate your main activity but simply switch to this fragment.

Comment: I created a seperate Activity for it because I also want to navigate to it from a PreferencesActivity... But actually a good input